# How to use concurrently in Yarn package?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

The default package manager in my system is Yarn. I am trying to follow a course that uses NPM. Instead of shifting to NPM, I wanted to continue in Yarn but I got stuck in concurrently. How can I convert the following code for Yarn?

```json
    "start": "node backend/server",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "data:import": "node backend/seeder",
    "data:destroy": "node backend/seeder -d",
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yarn version for above code will be:

```
"start": "node backend/server",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server",
    "client": "yarn --cwd frontend start",
    "dev": "concurrently \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\"",
    "data:import": "node backend/seeder",
    "data:destroy": "node backend/seeder -d"
```

[CWD](https://yarnpkg.com/package/cwd) - current working directory

Comment: yarn run v1.22.19
$ concurrently "yarn start" "yarn start-backend"
/bin/sh: 1: concurrently: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.

Comment: Hey @jrwren, you need to install it, like: yarn add concurrently